# PHP include but keep flash content always?

Tags: php, flash, include

Is it possible to have flash content(mp3 player) to always stay on a main html page that uses php include when switching between pages?(home/about/contact etc)?

SOLUTION:
I used SCM music player plugin, and also dedicated html page for MP3 playing.

Comment: Yes, it's called frames. Or ajax to switch pages.

Comment: Can you give me an example of using ajax for this purpose, since I don't want to use iframes for this?

Comment: I'd use jQuery. At it's basic level, you'll just make the links load into your content div. I'll write a quick answer, but read this: http://api.jquery.com/load/

Comment: That would be exactly what I am looking for, since I already designed/coded all the pages for the site. Awaiting your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say you content is set up like so:

```
<ul id="nav">
  <li><a href="/some/link">Go Here</a></li>
  <li><a href="/some/other/link">Go Here Instead</a></li>
</ul>
<div id="flash">
  <!-- mp3 player -->
</div>
<div id="content>
  <!-- main content -->
</div>
```

We can tell those links to load in the `#content` div rather than redirect the whole page. Using jQuery:

```
$('ul#nav li a').click(function() {
  $('#content').load($(this).attr('href'));
  return false;
}):
```

The link's content will now load into the `#content` div. Obviously there are repercussions: the browser's url doesn't change, the content needs to be view only (no top-level layout) unless you use jQuery's "partial load", etc.

It's not ideal. I'd say just open a new window for the player entirely.

Comment: I will try that. What if one of the pages that load inside #content includes links to other html pages? How do you tell those to also load in the same div on the parent page? E.g: Main page -> Click on nav-news -> News.html loads -> contains link to News1.html.

Comment: You could use the `load()` success callback to change those links. This could get unwieldy fast. I would add a `data-ajax = "true"` attribute and have jQuery look for those and make them into ajax links. A lot of this depends on your layout/view setup, too.

Comment: I tried the jQuery code but it doesn't seem to work for me, I replaced $(this) with $(#main). (I also tried to email you for a question through your site but don't think it worked).

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, fixed my contact page. I have the wrong selector, that's why it didn't work. Updated the answer. Should target the `a` tags. And yes, it should target the content div, that was my bad.

Answer (score 0):

If you need a continuous player, which won't stop playback between page changes, you'll have to design your webpage / application in order to do so.

These are the main approaches:

1. browse the website content within an `<iframe>`, so the player always stays alive on top [like [Beatport](http://www.beatport.com/) did times ago];
2. open your player in a small popup [a separate browser window], then keep playlist info in a session that will be required on every page load;
3. delegate all the navigation client side, so you'll never issue a full page reload [e.g. like GMail does].

First option is dirtiest, second one is fair but lives on that little hack [don't know how it works in mobile environment], third one is the best though it requires an overall bigger *skill* to achieve - no vanilla PHP, no messy jQuery dollar-ocean.

Last thought: stick with HTML 5 `<audio>` with Flash fallback as the extreme resort, but do not rely on Flash as your first technology.

Comment: As I said I don't want to use iframes because I encountered several issues(which I can list if you like). That's how I designed it at first place though.

Comment: I won't go with iframes either, I'd stick with options 2 or 3, with 3 being more future-proof, and 2 quicker to get things done.

Comment: Can you give me more info about the second method? If I chose to switch to full html elements for the website(instead of having an iframe or php include) it would be needed to use such a method because the mp3 is crucial for this project.